# Read range of numbers into a for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, interactive

So, I am building a bash script which iterates through folders named by numbers from 1 to 9. The script depends on getting the folder names by user input. My intention is to use a `for loop` using `read` input to get a folder name or a range of folder names and then do some stuff.

**Example:**
Let's assume I want to make a backup with `rsync -a` of a certain range of folders. Usually I would do:

```
for p in {1..7}; do
     rsync -a $p/* backup.$p
done
```

The above would recursively backup all content in the directories 1 2 3 4 5 6 and 7 and put them into folders named as 'backup.{index-number}'. It wouldn't catch folders/files with a leading `.` but that is not important right now.

Now I have a similar loop in an interactive bash script. I am using `select` and `case` statements for this task. One of the options in `case` is this loop and it shall somehow get a range of numbers from user input. This now becomes a problem.

**Problem:**
If I use `read` to get the range then it fails when using `{1..7}` as input. The input is taken literally and the output is just:

> {1..7}

I really would like to know why this happens. Let me use a more descriptive example with a simple `echo` command.

```
var={1..7} # fails and just outputs {1..7}
for p in $var; do echo $p;done

read var # Same result as above. Just outputs {1..7}
for p in $var; do echo $p;done

for p in {1..7}; do echo $p;done # works fine and outputs the numbers 1-7 seperated with a newline.
```

I've found a workaround by storing the numbers in an array. The user can then input folder names seperated by a space character like this: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

```
read -a var # In this case the output is similar to the 3rd loop above
for p in ${var[@]}; do echo $p; done
```

This could be a way to go but when backing up 40 folders ranging from 1-40 then adding all the numbers one-by-one completely makes my script redundant. One could find a solution to one of the millennium problems in the same time.

**Is there any way to `read` a range of numbers like {1..9} or could there be another way to get input from terminal into the script so I can iterate through the range within a `for-loop`?**

This sounds like a question for google but I am obviously using the wrong patterns to get a useful answer. Most of similar looking issues on SO refer to brace and parameter expansion issues but this is not exactly the problem I have. However, to me it feels like the answer to this problem is going in a similar direction. I fail to understand why when a `for-loop` for assigning `{1..7}` to a variable works but doing the same like `var={1..7}` doesn't. Plz help -.-

EDIT: My bash version:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.2.25(1)-release
```

**EDIT2: The versatility of a brace expansion is very important to me. A possible solution should include the ability to define as many ranges as possible. Like I would like to be able to choose between backing up just 1 folder or a fixed range between f.ex 4-22 and even multiple options like folders 1,2,5,6-7**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brace expansion is not performed on the right-hand side of a variable, or on parameter expansion. Use a C-style for loop, with the user inputing the upper end of the range if necessary.

```
read upper
for ((i=1; i<=$upper; i++)); do
```

To input both a lower and upper bound separated by whitespace

```
read lower upper
for (i=$lower; i <= $upper; i++)); do
```

---

For an arbitrary set of values, just push the burden to the user to generate the appropriate list; don't try to implement your own parser to process something like `1,2,20-22`:

```
while read p; do
    rsync -a $p/* backup.$p
done
```

The input is one value per line, such as

```
1
2
20
21
22
```

Even if the user is using the shell, they can call your script with something like

```
printf '%s\n' 1 2 20..22 | backup.sh
```

It's easier for the user to generate the list than it is for you to safely parse a string *describing* the list.

Comment: If I use `{1..7}` when running the script I get this error  

` ((: i<={1..7}: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{1..7}")`

Comment: The input is just the upper bound (7), not a brace expansion to specify the entire range. I added an option to specify both the lower and upper bounds (again as `1 7`, not `{1..7}`).

Comment: Ah, I see. The intention of my script is to be able to apply any range of numbers. So it needs to work if I just want 1 folder to be backed up or a range of folders between 2 and 20 or between 4 and 8 or even like 1,2,3,20-22  
That's why the brace expansion is so important to me. Your answer helped me quite a bit already. Mainly as I am not into C-Style for loops. I can't except it as it isn't as versatile as I would like it to be. I openly admit I should have made this more clear in my question though. I'll add it right now. Thank you very much so far!

Comment: For an arbitrary set of values, you are better off simply reading one value per line from standard input, and letting the user worry about how to generate the input.

Comment: How could that look like? That's actually a new question right?

Comment: I'll add something here.

Comment: Alright. Now I understand. Using a `while-loop` is a bit like my last example in the OP where I am storing a space seperated list of numbers in an array with `read -a`. The downside is all folders need to be entered one-by-one which quickly becomes annoying on a larger set of folders. Yes, piping numbers to the script is an advantage of your `while` but as the backup is just 1 option of many in a `case` statement it's not an option for me. I should probably start to learn a proper coding language then doing stuff like this with bash.

Comment: I'll leave the question open for a few more hours. Just in case someone else has a blasting idea to this. Technically you've answered it and if none comes up with something more satisfying I'll accept it. Cheers for the help! :)

Comment: god dammit! "Brace expansion is not performed on the right-hand side of a variable...." thank you - I just lost 15 minutes trying to figure out what was going on

Answer (score -2):

The evil `eval`

```
$ var={1..7}
$ for i in $(eval echo $var); do echo $i; done
```

this also works,

```
$ var="1 2 {5..9}"
$ for i in $(eval echo $var); do echo $i; done
1
2
5
6
7
8
9
```

evil eval was a joke, that is, as long as you know what you're evaluating.

Or, with `awk`

```
$ echo "1 2 5-9 22-25" | 
  awk -v RS=' '  '/-/{split($0,a,"-"); while(a[1]<=a[2]) print a[1]++; next}1'

1
2
5
6
7
8
9
22
23
24
25
```

Comment: Yea, I've read about the evil `eval` in other SO threads similar to my issue. It works but also echos `{1..7}`. I'm slightly in doubt how `eval` behaves with `rsync` or rather more complicated commands. Like when adding tests.